# MySQL connection refused "ERRNO 111" using Python mysql.connection library

Tags: python, mysql

**For context:**
I'm doing a personal web scraping project using Selenium, just getting some text and links (href attribute). I want to store this data on a database that I have on a VM running CentOS 7 with mariadb.
I create the connection like this:

```
import mysql.connector
conector = mysql.connector.connect(user='exampleusr', password='examplepasswd', host='192.168.1.32', database='exampledb')
cursor = conector.cursor()
```

And I use it twice, to insert into my DB and to query it.
Here

```
    fecha_hoy = date.today()
    for x in ofertas:
        try:
            sql = "INSERT INTO Ofertas VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"
            val = (fecha_hoy, x.text.partition('\n')[0], x.get_attribute('href'))
            cursor.execute(sql, val)
            conector.commit()

        except:
            continue
```

And here

```
    fecha_hoy = date.today()
    sql = "SELECT oferta, URL FROM Ofertas WHERE fecha = '{}'".format(fecha_hoy)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

For some weird reason that I can't figure out, the query works just fine, and I can insert into the database using the python shell and even inserting test data from other parts of the program. But that insert segment in particular won't work and it always gives me "Errno 111: Connection refused" as the exception.

UPDATE: I'm 100% sure now that the issue has something to do with how I'm inserting the data. I tried replacing that with some example insert sentence like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Ofertas VALUES('testvalue', 'testvalue', 'testvalue')"
cursor.execute(sql)
conector.commit()
```

and it works. Still can't figure out why the original sentence won't work.

Ofertas' CREATE TABLE:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                           |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Ofertas | CREATE TABLE `Ofertas` (
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `oferta` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URL` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`URL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

*EDIT:
Turns out the entire problem was caused by "ofertas" being null (Python's "None") when it got to inserting the data into my database. Already fixed that and everything works now.
Still, I hope this thread helps programmers (specially newbies like me) double check code just in case errors are not where everything points to.

Comment: do you have your lampp server running backend?

Comment: yup, everything but that insert part works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, be sure to consistently use [parameterization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) and not use it once and elsewhere concatenate and quote Python values to SQL statements.

Specifically, Python's `date.today()` being a `<class 'datetime.date'>` type is not in a suitable format that can be used in a concatenated statement expecting a string type in `WHERE fecha = '{}'`. However, parameterizaton may work which you did use in first code block but not in latter code blocks.

```py
fecha_hoy = date.today()
sql = "SELECT oferta, URL FROM Ofertas WHERE fecha = %s"

cursor.execute(sql, (fecha_hoy,))           # PARAMS PASSED AS TUPLE
```

Alternatively, convert the datetime type into a string, formatted in the standard ISO date format  `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```py
fecha_hoy = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sql = "SELECT oferta, URL FROM Ofertas WHERE fecha = %s"

cursor.execute(sql, [fecha_hoy])            # PARAMS PASSED AS LIST
```

---

By the way, consider [**`executemany`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) and avoid `for` loops

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO Ofertas (fecha, oferta, URL) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

vals = [(fecha_hoy, x.text.partition('\n')[0], x.get_attribute('href')) for x in ofertas]
    
cursor.executemany(sql, vals)
conector.commit()
```

Comment: I used parameterization everywhere like you said and tried both with the date as a date type and as a formatted date as a string and neither worked. Still, thanks for the advice, I'm new to Python so every bit of knowledge is good to have.

Comment: Please describe what happens. Errors? Undesired results? *Doesn't work* is never a helpful descriptor.

Comment: What query did you attempt that *did not work*? `SELECT`? `INSERT`? Both? Post any errors. Also, it is recommended to always explicitly declare columns in `INSERT`. See edit.

Comment: Uh you're right, my bad there. I added the error message to the main comment so it's readable.

Comment: First, you should not attempt to edit my answer with your error but edit your original post. Did you declare columns in `INSERT` as I mentioned? Looking closer that error does not appear to relate to query execution but connection attempt. Does error occur if you only run `connector = mysql.connector.connect(...)`?

Comment: Oh my bad again, I'm still a newbie to stack overflow.
I did try that but nothing changed. 
As I said earlier, everything about the connection works except for inserting into my table. I can query the database without any errors. 
I also tried inserting test data into the table using the Python shell and it also works.

Comment: What is the data type of `fecha`? Don't guess. Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE Ofertas` so we can see types and any constraints. I am really convinced your looping is the issue. Was inserted test data run inside loop? Your post shows isolated code blocks but not one clean, contiguous reproducible example. Please run this code snippet (https://pastebin.com/vWdCNSaK).

Comment: I updated the original post with the output of Ofertas' CREATE TABLE. I came to the same conclusion that the issue was with the loop, but even now using executemany() the issue persists.
The code snippet ran just fine, without any errors, and the data was inserted successfully.

Comment: In `executemany`, how are you assigning date? Use `fecha_hoy = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. Issue may be the other values. Your create table indicates URL cannot be `NULL` (or Python's `None`). Try your loop but print `val` before `execute`. Once error is raised check console for last printed set of values. By the way, how many items are being looped? If millions, you may have timeout issues.

Comment: I've tried both formatting the date on Python and using MySQL's CURDATE() function, both end up on the same error.  
There should be less than 100 items being looped.
So, I ran the code again, this time trying to print vals. Turns out the exception occurs during the declaration of vals (I checked this by printing before and after it).

Comment: So ultimately issue is whatever you are scraping and not SQL. Be sure to check the existence of a node before extracting its text or attribute. Also, `try...except` should have captured all these errors. Be sure to correctly place them around necessary code like how `ofertas` tuple/list is assigned. Without your full code block, I cannot tell. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Ok so... probably a rookie mistake by my side (though that error message didn't help). Turns out "ofertas" was null when it got to inserting the data into my database. I've corrected that and now everything works.
I must say, sorry for all the trouble and thanks a lot for everything, I really learned a lot from all this.